# Factors of $2^{80} - 1$ (how to factorize $2^m+1$)

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I'm trying to simplify $2^{80} - 1$ but having problems with factorizing $2^x+1$ elements.

What I got:

$2^{80}-1 = (2^{40})^2 - 1 = (2^{40} -1)(2^{40}+1) = ((2^{20})^2 - 1)(2^{40}+1) = (2^{20}-1)(2^{20}+1)(2^{40} + 1) = (2^{10} - 1)(2^{10} + 1)(2^{20}+1)(2^{40} + 1) = (2^5-1)(2^5+1)(2^{10} + 1)(2^{20}+1)(2^{40} + 1)$

So the problem is how do I factorize the $2^x+1$ elements, is there a formula which works for some cases?

Comment: Whenever $m$ is odd, $x=-1$ is a zero of $f(x)=x^m+1$. Hence
$$x^m+1=(x+1)(x^{m-1}-x^{m-2}+\cdots+x^2-x+1).$$
Parity is important for otherwise the alternating signs don't work out right. Anyway,
$$2^{40}+1=x^5+1,$$ where $x=2^8$ et cetera.

Comment: $2^{40}+1=257\cdot 4278255361$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the general formula
$$a^k+b^k = (a+b)(a^{k-1}-a^{k-2}b + a^{k-3}b^2 -\ldots - ab^{k-2}+b^{k-1})$$
for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$ **odd**.

For instance, $2^{40}+1 = (2^8)^5+1^5 = 256^5+1^5 = 257 \cdot (256^4 - 256^3 + 256^2 - 256 +1)$